# Drupal 10 and Docker do not see code changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal

I made a docker-compose file for Drupal 10, but with any edits to the code nothing changes, it's like Docker is caching.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./.mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - internal
      - external
    volumes:
      - drupal-data:/var/www/html

networks:
  external:
    driver: bridge
  internal:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  drupal-data:
```

Running docker-compose up -d

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Indeed docker is caching. What code are you modifying? What are the commands you are using?

Comment: Created new theme, installed new theme with composer, and I just create an error in the index.php file and nothing happens...